# can't call json var from inside a ajax .done

Tags: javascript, json

this is my code

```
.done(function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.['a']);
    console.log(data.a);
}
```

the json is

```
{"a":"5","b":"1","c":"4","d":"49","e":"154","f":"148"}
```

and the result is

```
{"a":"5","b":"1","c":"4","d":"49","e":"154","f":"148"} 
undefined
undefined
```

Anyone has any idea what could be the problem
I am sure it is something obvious

Comment: And do you really have JSON, as in a string, or do you have an object. Do `console.log( typeof data ) ` and tell us what that says.

Comment: what is the response code of your request? 200?

Comment: I think it should work look at here http://jsfiddle.net/4kz2Z/.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to adeneo
after realising that the var type was String instead of array
i just used

```
var res = JSON.parse(data);
```

Comment: you should question _why_ the var type was `String` instead of your JSON decoded into an `Object` - if your server correctly supplied JSON then the latter is what you should have had.